# Highlighting multiple selections on a form after submitting

Tags: php, jquery, html, post, get

This select box below does remember and highlight -one- selection after submitting the form. But when i make it multiple, it doesn't highlight any of the selectionS after submitting.
Any idea about how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$options_amount = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10+");
$no_way = $_GET['no_way'];
?>

<select class="postform" name="no_way[]" multiple size="5">
<option <?php if ($no_way == 'all') { ?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="all">Any</option>
<?php
foreach ($options_amount as $option) {
?><option <?php if ($no_way == $option) { ?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></option><?php }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$options_amount = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10+");
$no_way = $_GET['no_way'];
?>
<select class="postform" name="no_way[]" multiple size="5">
<option <?php if (in_array("all",$no_way)) { ?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="all">Any</option>
<?php
foreach ($options_amount as $option) {
?><option <?php if (in_array($option,$no_way)) { ?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></option><?php }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET['no_way']` only handles single parameters you have to use `$_GET['no_way[]']` and `in_array($option, $no_way)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but is there any chance you've tried just using `selected` instead of `selected="selected"`?

```
<option <?php if ($no_way == $option) { ?> selected<?php }?> value="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></option>
```