# PHP Form - Highlight multiple selection for SQL query

Tags: php, sql, forms

I'm trying to keep multiple options selected in a dropdown form after being submitted but I can't get it to work.  The options don't stay selected.  I've seen answers for this using foreach() ([Highlighting multiple selections on a form after submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674325/highlighting-multiple-selections-on-a-form-after-submitting)), however my data comes from a SQL query so I believe I need to use while() to loop through the rows.  Any thoughts?

```
$id7 = $_REQUEST['id7'];// Interest Level

<?php
$getParameter_sql4 = 'SELECT Funds.[Interest Level] FROM Funds GROUP BY Funds.[Interest Level] ORDER BY Funds.[Interest Level]';
$getParameter4 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$getParameter_sql4);
?>

<form action="/Reports/FundStatistics.php" method="get">

<select name="id7[]" multiple size="4">
<?php while ($row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getParameter4, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
<option <?php if (in_array($row4['Interest Level'],$id7)) { echo 'selected="selected"';}?> value="'<?php echo $row4['Interest Level']; ?>'"><?php echo $row4['Interest Level']; ?></option><?php }?>
</select>

<input type="submit" VALUE="Update" /></form>
```

Comment: I'm thinking it may have to do with the single quotes outside the php in this which I need when passing thru to the query: "'<?php echo $row4['Interest Level']; ?>'".

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to remove the single quotes from $id7 using a str_replace() and use this in the in_array().